# How to create a new source file in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I downloaded the Pharo launcher and stable appimage for version 9.0 in Windows 10. Now I want to try a hello world program, but I can't see a "create new file" option.

How do I create a new source file?

Comment: In Smalltalk you don't create a new source file for your program. You create a new package and one or more classes in it. Then add methods to those classes.

Comment: Almost obligatory quote from Kent Beck: “I mean, source code in files; how quaint, how seventies!” (Funny how most languages actually still use source files, but that was the quote at the time...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** adding examples and adding information

You should understand the original philosophy of the Smalltalk.

The whole OS was supposed to be written in Smalltalk and the GUI was to call the Smalltalk libraries in the OS.

The whole IDE was meant to be an enclosed world.  It did not evolve that way so now Smalltalk has to communicate with the outside world somehow, but it kept its ways when creating new code.

For your hello world application you need to, either use *Transcript* (`Transcript show: 'Hello World'`)  for short, testing code or as Leandro has written create a 'HelloWorld' package.

An example of such package:

```
Object subclass: #Greeting
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'HelloWorld'
```

You can find nice tutorials already created so please take advantage of those.  I'll direct you to one, which contains answer to your question:

[Pharo quick start by Richard Kenneth](https://richardeng.medium.com/pharo-quick-start-5bab70944ce2)

Comment: Thank you. The suggested link shows all the steps to create a new package "helloWorld" but it has confusing instructions in the "create a method" section.

Comment: @aks To write a new method you can click on the `+ Inst. side method` tab, erase the template code, and enter your code. Or you can click on any existing method, erase the contents of the lower pane and enter your code. To save the method use Ctrl+s.

Comment: Thank you @LeandroCaniglia for pointing that out.